# to subset a dataframe based on year and month

Tags: r

I want to subset my  dataframe from Sept 2017 to April 2018. My dataframe is like this:-

```
Year    Month   Day    Avg_Temp
2017    8       31      20
2017    9       1       22
.
.
.
2018    4       30      26
2018    5        1      30
```

I want that my dataset from 1 Sept 2017 to 30 April 2018.

```
Year    Month   Day    Avg_Temp
2017    9       1       22
.
.
.
2018    4       30      26
```

based on just the year I am to do subset.

```
df <-df[df$YEAR>="2017" & df$YEAR<="2018", ]
```

But I need to subset from month as well. Any help would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a `dplyr` approach:

```
 require(tidyverse)
   df<-data.frame(Year=c(2018,2017,2017,2017,2018,2018,2018),
               Month=c(9,8,10,4,9,3,4),Day=c(13,12,14,15,17,15,14))
df %>% 
  filter(Year==2017&Month>=9|Year==2018&Month<=4)
```

Which Yields this:

```
       Year Month Day
1      2017     9  14
2      2018     3  15
3      2018     4  14
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Using this:- RawWeatherBoston %>% filter(YEAR==2017&MONTH%in%c(4:7)), I am  able to get data from April 2017 to July 2017. I want to get data from Sept 2017 to April 2018.

Comment: I've updated my answer. See if that works for you. I for some reason took Sept to be 7, my bad!

Answer (score 1):

Try this option:

```
df <- df[(df$Year == 2017 & df$Month >= 9) |
         (df$Year == 2018 & df$Month <= 4), ]
```

By the way, you might want to consider storing your dates as a proper date type, including a day component.

Comment: I tried this but this isn't working. It is not filtering anything. Also the data type of Year is changing to  Logical(YEAR             : logi  TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE)

Comment: @supriyasingh Sorry, I had a typo in there.  It works now.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it would be easier if the three date components were encoded in one `Date` column :

```
df$Date <- as.Date(paste(df$Year, df$Month, df$Date, sep = '-'))
df$Year <- NULL
df$Month <- NULL

df <- df[df$Date > as.Date('2017-09-01') & df$Date < as.Date('2018-04-01'), ]
```

Comment: I don't want to combine all three columns. I need 3 separate columns for Year, Month and Day